# Pandas groupby time based on value in column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
data = {'lat':[4.2471, 4.2646,4.2945, 4.2819,4.2635,4.2616,4.2731,4.2555,5.2555],
        'lng':[-76.7504,-76.7198,-76.7069,-76.7251,-76.726,-76.7196,-76.715,-76.7118,-77.7118],
       'x':[208.999,-894.0,-171.0,108.999,-162.0,-29.0,-143.999,-133.0,-900.0],
       'e':[0.105,0.209,0.934,0.150,0.158,0.347,0.333,0.089,0.189],
       'dep':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['2020-01-01 16:32:14.105000-05:00', '2020-01-01 16:32:14.112000-05:00',
                                '2020-01-01 16:32:14.175000-05:00', '2020-01-01 16:32:14.176000-05:00',
                                '2020-01-01 16:32:14.211000-05:00','2020-01-01 16:32:14.220000-05:00',
                               '2020-01-01 16:32:14.310000-05:00','2020-01-01 16:32:14.327000-05:00',
                               '2020-01-01 16:32:15.327000-05:00'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

the idea is to filter the values in the column 'dep' and then groupby the rows that occurs in the same second and get the one with the max value in other column, I'm doing this for just one value but I need to do it for a large dataframe.

This is what I have so far:

```
df['x_ABS']=df['x'].abs()
d=df[(df['dep']=='a')]
idx = d.groupby([d.index.floor('s')])['x_ABS'].transform(max) == d['x_ABS']
d[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to use a `resample` to get per-second max of `x`. Here is sample code (note I made a copy named `df_`):

```
df_ = df[df['dep']=='a'].copy()
df_['x'] = df_['x'].abs()
df_.index = df_.index.floor('s')
df_['x'] = df_.resample('s').transform(max)['x']
```

Output:

```
                               lat      lng     x         e     dep
2020-01-01 16:32:14-05:00   4.2471  -76.7504    894.0   0.105   a
2020-01-01 16:32:14-05:00   4.2646  -76.7198    894.0   0.209   a
2020-01-01 16:32:14-05:00   4.2945  -76.7069    894.0   0.934   a
```

Comment: the idea is to get the rows for the others values, a,b,c